# Retrieve only todays data from SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server

I need to retrieve only today's data from a SQL Server database table.

I am developing an application in C#, VS 2010 and there is need that to retrieve only today's data.

Not getting the exact query how should it be. Also need to retrieve that data `order by Desc`.

How can we do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM <table_name> 
WHERE  <date_field> >= CONVERT(<date_field>, 
DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()))ORDER BY <date_field> DESC
```

Answer (score 3):

Yoou have to take the Date_time Column in Your TABLE That will keep the information of time when your row entered in table.

```
SELECT        Date_Time
FROM          TableThantYouWantAcees
WHERE         Date_Time = CONVERT(date, Getdate())
ORDER BY      Date_Time DESC
```

GETDATE() is an SQLServer function which will return the today date, like 2013-11-20 14:05:54.943. Cast it in DATE to only keep the date part, ie 2013-11-20.

Answer (score 1):

Extract the date part from your `date_column` with `convert`

```
select * from your_table
where CONVERT (DATE, date_column) = CONVERT (DATE, GETDATE()) 
order by date_column desc
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned about only having the date and not the time, you could so something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM tblPhoneAsign
WHERE receivedTime > CAST(FLOOR(CAST(GETDATE() AS FLOAT))AS DATETIME)
```

That will give you only the date portion of today's date. Doing the adding of zero hours to the GETDATE method is a very complex and costly way of doing things.